# Activity does not respond and RecyclerView not reflecting changes

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask, android-adapter

I am making an Android SMS app.
I have used a **RecyclerView** to show all the messages.

***SmsAdapter.java***   :

```
public class SmsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SmsAdapter.SmsViewHolder>{
    private static final String TAG = " [MY_DEBUG] ";

    ArrayList<String> sms_messages_list;
    Context context;

    public  SmsAdapter(Context ct, ArrayList<String> array_list){
        context = ct;
        sms_messages_list = array_list;
    }

    public void insert(int position, String new_sms) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SmsAdapter: insert(): adding a new message at position + " + position);
        sms_messages_list.add(position, new_sms);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

//more code here, might add if you guys ask so.
```

created the *SmsAdapter* object and initializing it with an item at index **0** in ***MainActivity.java***  :

```
        sms_messages_list.add(0, "dummy");
        sms_adapter = new SmsAdapter(this, sms_messages_list);
        messages.setAdapter(sms_adapter);
        messages.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

where `sms_messages_list` is an *ArrayList* and `messages` is the *RecyclerView*

I am using **AsyncTask** to read database in background thread (in the `doInBackground()`) and then adding items to the *SmsAdapter* inside the `onPostExecute()`.

***onPostExecute()***  :

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> msg_list) {
            super.onPostExecute(msg_list);
            MainActivity activity = activityWeakReference.get();
            if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing()) {
                return;
            }
            int j=0;
            try {
                    while (j < msg_list.size()) {
                    activity.sms_adapter.insert(j, msg_list.get(j).toString());
                    j++;
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: exception : " + e);
            }            
       db1.startTransaction();    // this line I did not put in original question and this is what caused the porblem  ... replaced it with db1.endTransaction() and code works 
       db1.close();
       }
```

where the `msg_list` is an *ArrayList* which has all the SMS messages in String format(one String item = one SMS)

////

***EDIT 1*** : Here is the entire *AsyncTask* code :
https://pastebin.com/q495VjMs

////

When I run this, I only see the one item that is "*dummy*" and the activity does not even respond. The database is correctly read, the msg_list has all the messages as expected. I am unable to find where I am going wrong in this. Please help!

App not responding

[image: App does not respond]

No other items showing in RecyclerView
[image: No other items showing in RecyclerView]

The only error in logcat:

```
2020-07-30 20:09:56.344 578-599/system_process E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.example.mynewsmsapp_kotlin (com.example.mynewsmsapp_kotlin/.MainActivity)
    PID: 2455
    Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 2.  Wait queue head age: 7166.5ms.)
```

PS: Excuse me for the weird name of my app. It does not make sense I know.

Comment: dont use assynctask, its deprecated. Use Rx or Coroutines. My guess is that acessing db is done on main thread and takes too long, thats why the "not responding " error.

Comment: Can you post your entire `asyncTask`?

Comment: @Rinat I have done db operations in doInBackground() , so I guess that happens in the background thread.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai yes here is the link https://pastebin.com/q495VjMs . Sorry my code is so messy. But I think there not problem in any other part because the logs properly show the contents of messages_list. Everything looks fine except the adapter. Please see where I went wrong if you have time.

Answer (score 0):

Please make this code to like this :

```
      public  SmsAdapter(Context ct, ArrayList<String> array_list){
               this.context = ct;
               this.sms_messages_list.addAll(array_list);
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        int j=0;
        try {
                while (j < msg_list.size()) {
                activity.sms_adapter.insert(msg_list.get(j).toString());
                j++;
                }
        }
        \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
        public void insert(String new_sms) {
            sms_messages_list.add(new_sms);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time. Unfortunately, this did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Earlier I by mistakely put `db.startTransaction()` instead of `db.endTransaction()` at the end of method `onPostExecute()`. Now I made it `db.endTrasaction()` and the code works.